# Using buttons in Tkinter to navigate to different pages of the application?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I have quite a simple question here. In Tkinter (python), I was wondering who to use a button to go to different pages of my application, e.g a register page, and a login page. I am aware that GUI does not have 'pages' like websites do, I've seen a few different ways, but what is the best way to make links to different pages?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Make each page a frame. Then, all your buttons need to do is hide whatever is visible, then make the desired frame visible.

A simple method to do this is to stack the frames on top of each other (this is one time when `place` makes sense) and then ,`lift()` the frame you want to be visible. This technique works best when all pages are the same size; in fact, it requires that you explicitly set the size of containing frame.

The following is a contrived example. This isn't the only way to solve the problem, just proof that it's not a particularly hard problem to solve:

```
import Tkinter as tk

class Page(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    def show(self):
        self.lift()

class Page1(Page):
   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       Page.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
       label = tk.Label(self, text="This is page 1")
       label.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

class Page2(Page):
   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       Page.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
       label = tk.Label(self, text="This is page 2")
       label.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

class Page3(Page):
   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       Page.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
       label = tk.Label(self, text="This is page 3")
       label.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

class MainView(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        p1 = Page1(self)
        p2 = Page2(self)
        p3 = Page3(self)

        buttonframe = tk.Frame(self)
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        buttonframe.pack(side="top", fill="x", expand=False)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

        p1.place(in_=container, x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
        p2.place(in_=container, x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
        p3.place(in_=container, x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)

        b1 = tk.Button(buttonframe, text="Page 1", command=p1.show)
        b2 = tk.Button(buttonframe, text="Page 2", command=p2.show)
        b3 = tk.Button(buttonframe, text="Page 3", command=p3.show)

        b1.pack(side="left")
        b2.pack(side="left")
        b3.pack(side="left")

        p1.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    main = MainView(root)
    main.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.wm_geometry("400x400")
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: than you so much, exactly what i was after!

Comment: @CasparWylie: All this example means is that this whole example is one block of text. You can divide it into as many files as you want -- that has nothing to do with the solution. Each "page" could easily be its own module.

Comment: @BryanOakley, wouldn't it be better to use notebook for things like this? http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/complex.html#notebook

Comment: @user3885927: as with most usability questions, "that depends". This question wasn't about what's best, but simply how to switch between pages. You could use a notebook, yes, or you can use this technique to create your own custom notebook. For example, if you had 100 pages, you could create a notebook that uses a listbox for the list of pages, rather than try to squeeze a bunch of tabs across the top of the widget.

Comment: How do I pass value of a variable from a function in MainView() to Page2()?

Comment: @BryanOakley Hi, is there a way of doing this (creating multiple pages) without using classes, only functions?

Comment: @AleksandarBeat: yes, of course. It might be a bit more cumbersome, but it's all just code.

Comment: @BryanOakley can you maybe post an example code, I have looked everywhere but I didn't find anything. You can answer here, on this question: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50671555/creating-multiple-pages-with-tkinter-without-using-class)

Comment: @Bryan: Is there some reason why you didn't have the `Button`s in `MainView` call the `show()` method instead of `lift()`? I ask because of question [tkinter: How to print a list when a Button is clicked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67893128/tkinter-how-to-print-a-list-when-a-button-is-clicked)

Comment: @martineau: that was a mistake. Thanks for pointing it out, I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 7):

Could you do something like this?

```
import tkinter

def page1():
    page2text.pack_forget()
    page1text.pack()

def page2():
    page1text.pack_forget()
    page2text.pack()

window = tkinter.Tk()

page1btn = tkinter.Button(window, text="Page 1", command=page1)
page2btn = tkinter.Button(window, text="Page 2", command=page2)

page1text = tkinter.Label(window, text="This is page 1")
page2text = tkinter.Label(window, text="This is page 2")

page1btn.pack()
page2btn.pack()
page1text.pack()
```

It seems a lot simpler to me.

Comment: @ResheilAgarwal Then you could make a function that would take the page to be hidden as the parameter.

Comment: Simpler if number of pages is 2. Not so simple if number of pages is 27.

Answer (score -1):

```
import tkinter as tk
root=tk.Tk()
root.geometry("360x360")

frame=tk.Frame(root,bg='lightblue')
frame.place(relx=0.2,rely=0.2,relheight=0.6,relwidth=0.6)

def page1():
    label=tk.Label(frame,text='this is the page1')
    label.place(relx=0.3,rely=0.4)

def page2():
    label=tk.Label(frame,text='this is the page2')
    label.place(relx=0.3,rely=0.4)

def page3():
    label=tk.Label(frame,text='this is the page3')
    label.place(relx=0.3,rely=0.4)

bt=tk.Button(root,text='page1',command=page1)
bt.grid(column=0,row=0)

bt1=tk.Button(root,text='page2',command=page2)
bt1.grid(row=0,column=1)

bt2=tk.Button(root,text='page3',command=page3)
bt2.grid(row=0,column=2)

root.mainloop()`
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to your code: What does it do, how does it work, how does it solve OPs problem, and what makes it different from the existing answers. Code only answers can lead to [cargo cult programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming), and you risk getting downvotes.