# Tkinter NavigationToolbar2TkAgg - TypeError "Label object is not callable"

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I am making a gui using `tkinter` that takes in data points "dollars" and plots them onto a matplotlib chart. I understand to embed a `matplotlib` plot onto `tkinter` requires using `FigureCanvasTkAgg` and `NavigationToolbar2TkAgg`. This method works when I didn't use inheritance between parent class and child class.

When I tried to implement multiple pages into my program, like the link below:

[Using buttons in Tkinter to navigate to different pages of the application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14817210/using-buttons-in-tkinter-to-navigate-to-different-pages-of-the-application)

My function is under the `Page1` class, which is a subclass of the `Page` class. I started getting an unresponsive toolbar whenever I pressed buttons. With the `TypeError "Label object is not callable`.

I know the error is coming from declaring the `NavigationToolbar2TkAgg` object. Please help, I suspect I might have an inheritance issue since I created a separate frame for toolbar and `Figure` canvas.

```
def plot_data(self,dollars):
    """
        This function takes in a list for dollars calculates
        the years and converts the lists into numpy arrays and plots
        them onto a matplotlib figure embedded into tkinter.

    """
    #create a figure object to hold the matplotlib plots
    self.figure = Figure(figsize=(5,4), dpi = 100)

    #create a subplot first row first column
    self.a = self.figure.add_subplot(111)

    #update the list of dollars for the plot
    self.dollars = np.array(dollars)
    self.years = np.arange(0,len(dollars),1)

    #plots the numpy arrays into a matplotlib figure 'pyplot'
    self.a.plot(self.years,self.dollars,linestyle='none',marker='o')

    #holds matplotlib figure in a container to be displayed in tkinter window 'window'
    self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.figure, master=self)

    #show matplotlib figure on tkinter window
    self.canvas.show()

    #displays the matplotlib figure on the grid
    self.canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row=10,column=1,columnspan=2,rowspan=20)

    #create the toolbar synced with canvas
    self.toolbarFrame = tk.Frame(self)
    self.toolbarFrame.grid(row=31,column=1)

    #creates a navigation toolbar linked to the matplotlib figure with
    #the master being the toolbar tk.Frame
    self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar2TkAgg(self.canvas,self.toolbarFrame)

    #update the plot
    self.toolbar.update()
```

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed my issue. The code above does not contain any issues. I actually declared one of my instance variables in my class incorrectly.

Here is the error I made:

TypeError: Label object is not callable
Ex) tk.Label = tk.Label(.....)

Feel free to use the function above to embed a figure and navigation bar to your tkinter GUI as it works.