# How to Place a frame

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, frame

I'm new to Tkinter and Python, Working from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14819141) Code as a baseline, I'd Like to Place the Button Frame for navigation to the different pages slightly raised from the bottom (inside [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8i7q.jpg)).

So how would I be able to .place the frame at that specific coordinates, or .grid it to the bottom right where i can pad it without obstructing the Pages?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [tkinter gui layout using frames and grid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34277295/7414759)

Comment: Decided to Work around the problem by replacing the whole bottom navigation with a frame instead of trying to place the frame into position. Going to leave the question up if in case someone has an answer.

Comment: ***replacing the whole bottom navigation with a frame***: That's the way to go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Mentioned and supported by @stovli, I found that the best solution is to rather cut off the bottom part of the frame and split it to its own frame and simply back it underneath the other frame. This results in a simpler design instead of managing frames on top of each other.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to move it from top border just use padding.

```
buttonframe.pack(side="top", fill="x", expand=False, pady=15)
```

If you want it to appear on bottom right, then pack buttons after container.

```
container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
buttonframe.pack(side="right", fill="x", expand=False, pady=15)
```

You can also use other commands than `.pack` like `.grid` [grid](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm) or `.place` [place](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/place.htm). Personally I prefer to use mix of `.grid` and `.pack`

Comment: Thanks for the Answers, Unfortunately , .grid and .place isn't an option as it results in an  error when used with the Container frame. And when Padding is used to lift it, it obstructs the image used in the Container.

I want to replicate accurate button Placing as [such](https://imgur.com/a/dxDf3dh), but rather place it on a still frame instead of placing it on each screen. Would my best option be to cut out the bottom navigation and replace the whole bottom with the frame?