# How to change the content of a tkinter window?

Tags: python, tkinter

How can I change my Tkinter window's content? Like a webpage where you click buttons to go to different places?

(Preferably without classes)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using buttons in Tkinter to navigate to different pages of the application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14817210/using-buttons-in-tkinter-to-navigate-to-different-pages-of-the-application)

Comment: I am looking for a simpler way. I haven't started learning classes yet..

Answer (score 1):

Your question is quite vague, but I believe the `ttk.Notebook` widget may be of use. Here is an example of how to have different tabs of content:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *

root = Tk()
tabmanager = Notebook(root)
tabmanager.pack(expand=1,fill="both")

tab1 = Frame(tabmanager)
tab2 = Frame(tabmanager)

tabmanager.add(tab1,text="Home")
tabmanager.add(tab2,text="About")

root.mainloop()
```

You can then add whatever widgets you like to the frames.
Hopefully this answers your question; let me know if you need more help :)

Comment: Sorry for the late response, this works but how could I make different canvases and put them in each frame. I'm a newbie to tkinter...

Comment: Just do `canvas1 = Canvas(tab1)` then `canvas1.pack()` or equivalent geometry manager.

Comment: thanks a lot. Could I implement a conditional. For example `if option ==1: goto tab2`