# i am using python page i created two top levels and don't know how to switch between both of them once i pressed correct login

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

from this page here i dont know how to destroy current page and move to the next.
which function do i need to use or is it possible in python page to create multiple top levels
if so how thank you.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
#  -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#
# GUI module generated by PAGE version 6.0
#  in conjunction with Tcl versioin 8.6
#    Nov 29, 2020 07:01:59 PM +0200  platform: Windows NT

import pymongo
import sys
from tkinter import messagebox

client = pymongo.MongoClient()
mydb = client['EZSchooldb']
try:
    import Tkinter as tk
except ImportError:
    import tkinter as tk

try:
    import ttk
    py3 = False
except ImportError:
    import tkinter.ttk as ttk
    py3 = True

import Login_Page_support
import Secretarymainmenu
import Studentmainmenu
import Teachermainmenu

def vp_start_gui():
    '''Starting point when module is the main routine.'''
    global val, w, root
    root = tk.Tk()
    top = Login_Page (root)
    Login_Page_support.init(root, top)
    root.mainloop()

w = None
def create_Login_Page(rt, *args, **kwargs):
    '''Starting point when module is imported by another module.
       Correct form of call: 'create_Login_Page(root, *args, **kwargs)' .'''
    global w, w_win, root
    #rt = root
    root = rt
    w = tk.Toplevel (root)
    top = Login_Page (w)
    Login_Page_support.init(w, top, *args, **kwargs)
    return (w, top)

def destroy_Login_Page():
    global w
    w.destroy()
    w = None

class Login_Page(tk.Frame):
    def login(self):
        user = self.ID__Entry.get()
        pws = self.Password_Entry.get()
        global mydb
        userobj = mydb['Users'].find_one({'id' :user})
        if userobj == None:
            tk.messagebox.showwarning(
                'Login Page', 
                'The Id or Password is incorrect'
            )

        elif pws == userobj['password']:
            tk.messagebox.showinfo(
                'Login Page', 
                f"Welcome {userobj['name']}")
            **#if userobj['Usertype'] == 1:
         #   elif userobj['Usertype'] == 2:
          #  elif userobj['Usertype'] == 3:**

        else:
            tk.messagebox.showwarning(
                'Login Page', 
                'The Id or Password is incorrect'
            )


    def __init__(self, top=None):
        '''This class configures and populates the toplevel window.
           top is the toplevel containing window.'''
        _bgcolor = '#d9d9d9'  # X11 color: 'gray85'
        _fgcolor = '#000000'  # X11 color: 'black'
        _compcolor = '#d9d9d9' # X11 color: 'gray85'
        _ana1color = '#d9d9d9' # X11 color: 'gray85'
        _ana2color = '#ececec' # Closest X11 color: 'gray92'

        top.geometry("600x525+660+210")
        top.minsize(148, 1)
        top.maxsize(1924, 1055)
        top.resizable(1,  1)
        top.title("Login_Page")
        top.configure(background="#ffffff")
        top.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
        top.configure(highlightcolor="black")

        self.menubar = tk.Menu(top,font="TkMenuFont",bg=_bgcolor,fg=_fgcolor)
        top.configure(menu = self.menubar)

        self.Login_Button = tk.Button(top)
        self.Login_Button.place(relx=0.283, rely=0.577, height=93, width=256)
        self.Login_Button.configure(activebackground="#ececec")
        self.Login_Button.configure(activeforeground="#000000")
        self.Login_Button.configure(background="#e7e7e7")
        self.Login_Button.configure(cursor="hand2")
        self.Login_Button.configure(disabledforeground="#a3a3a3")
        self.Login_Button.configure(foreground="#000000")
        self.Login_Button.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
        self.Login_Button.configure(highlightcolor="black")
        self.Login_Button.configure(pady="0")
        self.Login_Button.configure(text='''Login''')
        self.Login_Button.configure(command= self.login)

        self.Label1 = tk.Label(top)
        self.Label1.place(relx=0.217, rely=0.267, height=30, width=82)
        self.Label1.configure(activebackground="#f9f9f9")
        self.Label1.configure(activeforeground="black")
        self.Label1.configure(background="#ffffff")
        self.Label1.configure(disabledforeground="#a3a3a3")
        self.Label1.configure(foreground="#000000")
        self.Label1.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
        self.Label1.configure(highlightcolor="black")
        self.Label1.configure(text='''ID''')

        self.ID__Entry = tk.Entry(top)
        self.ID__Entry.place(relx=0.383, rely=0.267, height=34, relwidth=0.273)
        self.ID__Entry.configure(background="white")
        self.ID__Entry.configure(disabledforeground="#a3a3a3")
        self.ID__Entry.configure(font="TkFixedFont")
        self.ID__Entry.configure(foreground="#000000")
        self.ID__Entry.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
        self.ID__Entry.configure(highlightcolor="black")
        self.ID__Entry.configure(insertbackground="black")
        self.ID__Entry.configure(selectbackground="blue")
        self.ID__Entry.configure(selectforeground="white")

        self.Label2 = tk.Label(top)
        self.Label2.place(relx=0.2, rely=0.423, height=42, width=102)
        self.Label2.configure(activebackground="#f9f9f9")
        self.Label2.configure(activeforeground="black")
        self.Label2.configure(background="#ffffff")
        self.Label2.configure(disabledforeground="#a3a3a3")
        self.Label2.configure(foreground="#000000")
        self.Label2.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
        self.Label2.configure(highlightcolor="black")
        self.Label2.configure(text='''Password''')

        self.Password_Entry = tk.Entry(top)
        self.Password_Entry.place(relx=0.383, rely=0.423, height=34, relwidth=0.273)
        self.Password_Entry.configure(background="white")
        self.Password_Entry.configure(disabledforeground="#a3a3a3")
        self.Password_Entry.configure(font="TkFixedFont")
        self.Password_Entry.configure(foreground="#000000")
        self.Password_Entry.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
        self.Password_Entry.configure(highlightcolor="black")
        self.Password_Entry.configure(insertbackground="black")
        self.Password_Entry.configure(selectbackground="blue")
        self.Password_Entry.configure(selectforeground="white")

        self.Message1 = tk.Message(top)
        self.Message1.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.114, relheight=0.057
                , relwidth=0.677)
        self.Message1.configure(background="#ffffff")
        self.Message1.configure(foreground="#000000")
        self.Message1.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
        self.Message1.configure(highlightcolor="black")
        self.Message1.configure(text=''':נא להכניס פרטי משתמש''')
        self.Message1.configure(width=406)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    vp_start_gui()
```

```
to this page and few others

    #! /usr/bin/env python
#  -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#
# GUI module generated by PAGE version 5.6
#  in conjunction with Tcl version 8.6
#    Nov 29, 2020 09:43:22 PM +0200  platform: Windows NT

import sys

try:
    import Tkinter as tk
except ImportError:
    import tkinter as tk

try:
    import ttk
    py3 = False
except ImportError:
    import tkinter.ttk as ttk
    py3 = True

import Secretarymainmenu_support

def vp_start_gui():
    '''Starting point when module is the main routine.'''
    global val, w, root
    root = tk.Tk()
    top = secretarypage (root)
    Secretarymainmenu_support.init(root, top)
    root.mainloop()

w = None
def create_secretarypage(rt, *args, **kwargs):
    '''Starting point when module is imported by another module.
       Correct form of call: 'create_secretarypage(root, *args, **kwargs)' .'''
    global w, w_win, root
    #rt = root
    root = rt
    w = tk.Toplevel (root)
    top = secretarypage (w)
    Secretarymainmenu_support.init(w, top, *args, **kwargs)
    return (w, top)

def destroy_secretarypage():
    global w
    w.destroy()
    w = None

class secretarypage:
    def __init__(self, top=None):
        '''This class configures and populates the toplevel window.
           top is the toplevel containing window.'''
        _bgcolor = '#d9d9d9'  # X11 color: 'gray85'
        _fgcolor = '#000000'  # X11 color: 'black'
        _compcolor = '#d9d9d9' # X11 color: 'gray85'
        _ana1color = '#d9d9d9' # X11 color: 'gray85'
        _ana2color = '#ececec' # Closest X11 color: 'gray92'

        top.geometry("1920x1051+-9+-9")
        top.minsize(148, 1)
        top.maxsize(1924, 1055)
        top.resizable(1,  1)
        top.title("Secretary main menu")
        top.configure(background="#ffffff")
        top.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
        top.configure(highlightcolor="black")

        self.student_schedule = tk.Button(top)
        self.student_schedule.place(relx=0.219, rely=0.171, height=93, width=186)

        self.student_schedule.configure(activebackground="#ececec")
        self.student_schedule.configure(activeforeground="#000000")
        self.student_schedule.configure(background="#d9d9d9")
        self.student_schedule.configure(disabledforeground="#a3a3a3")
        self.student_schedule.configure(foreground="#000000")
        self.student_schedule.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
        self.student_schedule.configure(highlightcolor="black")
        self.student_schedule.configure(pady="0")
        self.student_schedule.configure(text='''עדכון מערכת שעות תלמיד''')

        self.teacher_schedule = tk.Button(top)
        self.teacher_schedule.place(relx=0.344, rely=0.17, height=93, width=186)
        self.teacher_schedule.configure(activebackground="#ececec")
        self.teacher_schedule.configure(activeforeground="#000000")
        self.teacher_schedule.configure(background="#d9d9d9")
        self.teacher_schedule.configure(disabledforeground="#a3a3a3")
        self.teacher_schedule.configure(foreground="#000000")
        self.teacher_schedule.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
        self.teacher_schedule.configure(highlightcolor="black")
        self.teacher_schedule.configure(pady="0")
        self.teacher_schedule.configure(text='''עדכון מערכת שעות מורה''')

        self.health = tk.Button(top)
        self.health.place(relx=0.474, rely=0.171, height=93, width=186)
        self.health.configure(activebackground="#ececec")
        self.health.configure(activeforeground="#000000")
        self.health.configure(background="#d9d9d9")
        self.health.configure(disabledforeground="#a3a3a3")
        self.health.configure(foreground="#000000")
        self.health.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
        self.health.configure(highlightcolor="black")
        self.health.configure(pady="0")
        self.health.configure(text='''הצהרת בריאות''')

        self.menubar = tk.Menu(top,font="TkMenuFont",bg=_bgcolor,fg=_fgcolor)
        top.configure(menu = self.menubar)

        self.meetings = tk.Button(top)
        self.meetings.place(relx=0.609, rely=0.171, height=93, width=186)
        self.meetings.configure(activebackground="#ececec")
        self.meetings.configure(activeforeground="#000000")
        self.meetings.configure(background="#d9d9d9")
        self.meetings.configure(disabledforeground="#a3a3a3")
        self.meetings.configure(foreground="#000000")
        self.meetings.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
        self.meetings.configure(highlightcolor="black")
        self.meetings.configure(pady="0")
        self.meetings.configure(text='''יומן פגישות''')

        self.work_clock = tk.Button(top)
        self.work_clock.place(relx=0.74, rely=0.171, height=93, width=186)
        self.work_clock.configure(activebackground="#ececec")
        self.work_clock.configure(activeforeground="#000000")
        self.work_clock.configure(background="#d9d9d9")
        self.work_clock.configure(disabledforeground="#a3a3a3")
        self.work_clock.configure(foreground="#000000")
        self.work_clock.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
        self.work_clock.configure(highlightcolor="black")
        self.work_clock.configure(pady="0")
        self.work_clock.configure(text='''שעון עבודה''')

        self.inventory_payment = tk.Button(top)
        self.inventory_payment.place(relx=0.219, rely=0.324, height=93
                , width=186)
        self.inventory_payment.configure(activebackground="#ececec")
        self.inventory_payment.configure(activeforeground="#000000")
        self.inventory_payment.configure(background="#d9d9d9")
        self.inventory_payment.configure(disabledforeground="#a3a3a3")
        self.inventory_payment.configure(foreground="#000000")
        self.inventory_payment.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
        self.inventory_payment.configure(highlightcolor="black")
        self.inventory_payment.configure(pady="0")
        self.inventory_payment.configure(text='''גביית תשלום - ציוד''')

        self.tuition_fee = tk.Button(top)
        self.tuition_fee.place(relx=0.344, rely=0.324, height=93, width=186)
        self.tuition_fee.configure(activebackground="#ececec")
        self.tuition_fee.configure(activeforeground="#000000")
        self.tuition_fee.configure(background="#d9d9d9")
        self.tuition_fee.configure(disabledforeground="#a3a3a3")
        self.tuition_fee.configure(foreground="#000000")
        self.tuition_fee.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
        self.tuition_fee.configure(highlightcolor="black")
        self.tuition_fee.configure(pady="0")
        self.tuition_fee.configure(text='''גביית תשלום - שכר לימוד''')

        self.teachers_survey = tk.Button(top)
        self.teachers_survey.place(relx=0.474, rely=0.324, height=93, width=186)
        self.teachers_survey.configure(activebackground="#ececec")
        self.teachers_survey.configure(activeforeground="#000000")
        self.teachers_survey.configure(background="#d9d9d9")
        self.teachers_survey.configure(disabledforeground="#a3a3a3")
        self.teachers_survey.configure(foreground="#000000")
        self.teachers_survey.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
        self.teachers_survey.configure(highlightcolor="black")
        self.teachers_survey.configure(pady="0")
        self.teachers_survey.configure(text='''סקר מורים''')

        self.forum = tk.Button(top)
        self.forum.place(relx=0.609, rely=0.324, height=93, width=186)
        self.forum.configure(activebackground="#ececec")
        self.forum.configure(activeforeground="#000000")
        self.forum.configure(background="#d9d9d9")
        self.forum.configure(disabledforeground="#a3a3a3")
        self.forum.configure(foreground="#000000")
        self.forum.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
        self.forum.configure(highlightcolor="black")
        self.forum.configure(pady="0")
        self.forum.configure(text='''פורום''')

        self.inventory_manage = tk.Button(top)
        self.inventory_manage.place(relx=0.74, rely=0.324, height=93, width=186)
        self.inventory_manage.configure(activebackground="#ececec")
        self.inventory_manage.configure(activeforeground="#000000")
        self.inventory_manage.configure(background="#d9d9d9")
        self.inventory_manage.configure(disabledforeground="#a3a3a3")
        self.inventory_manage.configure(foreground="#000000")
        self.inventory_manage.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
        self.inventory_manage.configure(highlightcolor="black")
        self.inventory_manage.configure(pady="0")
        self.inventory_manage.configure(text='''ניהול מלאי ציוד משרדי''')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    vp_start_gui()
```

In class Login_Page function Login i try to open diffrent top levels acording to user classification which is 1-3 using mongodb i cheack the user data i stored in my database
thank you in advance for the help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14817210/using-buttons-in-tkinter-to-navigate-to-different-pages-of-the-application