# tkinter: How to print a list when a Button is clicked?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am using tkinter and my goal is to print list L inside class `Page2(Page)` whenever I click on Page 2. Currently, if you run the code, you can see that letters A & B are being printed in the console once you are in Page 1 which means that tkinter has already gone through that for loop. How can I change this code to go through that for loop only if I click on Page 2? FYI, I borrowed the code from the answer to [Using buttons in Tkinter to navigate to different pages of the application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14817210/using-buttons-in-tkinter-to-navigate-to-different-pages-of-the-application).

```
import tkinter as tk

class Page(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    def show(self):
        self.lift()

class Page1(Page):
   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       Page.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
       label = tk.Label(self, text="This is page 1")
       label.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

class Page2(Page):
   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       Page.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
       L=[]
       for x in ["A","B"]:
           print(x)
           L.append(x)
       label = tk.Label(self, text=L)
       label.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)


class Page3(Page):
   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       Page.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
       label = tk.Label(self, text="This is page 3")
       label.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

class MainView(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        p1 = Page1(self)
        p2 = Page2(self)
        p3 = Page3(self)

        buttonframe = tk.Frame(self)
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        buttonframe.pack(side="top", fill="x", expand=False)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

        p1.place(in_=container, x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
        p2.place(in_=container, x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
        p3.place(in_=container, x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)

        b1 = tk.Button(buttonframe, text="Page 1", command=p1.lift)
        b2 = tk.Button(buttonframe, text="Page 2", command=p2.lift)
        b3 = tk.Button(buttonframe, text="Page 3", command=p3.lift)

        b1.pack(side="left")
        b2.pack(side="left")
        b3.pack(side="left")

        p1.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    main = MainView(root)
    main.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.wm_geometry("400x400")
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's printing the list because that's part of creating an instance of the `Page2` class that occurs before it's made visible (if ever) — which is just an artifact of the architecture of the code in the answer you "borrowed".

Here's a way to fix things. First change the `Button` callback `command=` options in `MainView.__init__()` so the `show()` method will get called instead of `lift()`:

```
        b1 = tk.Button(buttonframe, text="Page 1", command=p1.show)
        b2 = tk.Button(buttonframe, text="Page 2", command=p2.show)
        b3 = tk.Button(buttonframe, text="Page 3", command=p3.show)
```

This means that each `Page` subclass' `show()` method will now be invoked whenever one of the `Button`s is clicked, which by default just calls its base class' `lift()` method, so all this does is add a level of indirection — thereby making it possible to easily override / extend it in subclasses like `Page2` to make them do whatever specialized processing might be needed.

Note that I also made `L` an *attribute* of the subclass' instances (instead of it being a local variable in the the `__init__()` method) to allow it to be easily referenced in the other method of the class.

```
class Page2(Page):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Page.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.L = []
        for x in ["A","B"]:
            self.L.append(x)
        label = tk.Label(self, text=self.L)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

    def show(self):
        print(f'in class {type(self).__name__}.show()')
        super().show()  # Call superclass' method.
        for x in self.L:
            print(x)
```

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: You're welcome. I suspect being able to do this was intentional — in other words, the author of the borrowed answer created a base class `show()` method precisely so it could be overridden by subclasses. Although, that said, I don't understand is why he didn't use it when defining the `Button`s.

Comment: Riddle solved — see [response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14817210/using-buttons-in-tkinter-to-navigate-to-different-pages-of-the-application/14819141?noredirect=1#comment120007281_14819141) when I asked the answer's author about this.