# What does it " tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs) " mean?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am a newbie. I've seen         `tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)` this code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14819141/14104530).
I am really confused. What exactly this would do?

Comment: Which part? `tk.Frame` is the TKinter frame class. The `*args, **kwargs` is a common idiom for forwarding arguments in Python

Comment: 'tk.Frame'  What does it do?

Answer (score 1):

This is fundamental part of python's standard way of creating subclasses. It doesn't really have anything specific to do with tkinter. However, if you subclass a tkinter class -- like with any class -- this will make sure that the base class is properly initialized.

What you're seeing, however, is an older style of initializing a base class. For python 3.x and beyond you should be using something like `super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)`. See [super](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super) and the description of [Class objects](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects) in the standard python documentation.